# Java - Error: NoSuchElementException: No Line Found

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I need to read strings from a file and store them in an array. However, my professor isn't allowing the class to use ArrayList. So I decided to run through the file once using `hasNextLine()` and counting how many lines there are then creating an array and making it equal to the amount of lines.

Then I made a while loop that is checking whether `i` is `<=` to the array, and giving the `array[i]` a value of `fileInput.nextLine();`. However, I seem to constantly get the error `NoSuchElementException: No line found`.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 1;

    //Read strings from a file and store in array
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("file.dat"));

    while(fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
        fileInput.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    String [] strArray = new String [count];

    while (i <= strArray.length) {
/*Error Here*/    strArray[i] = fileInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println(strArray[i]);
            i++;
    }
}
}
```

Would anyone know of a solution to my error?

P.S file.dat looks like this:

```
FRESH
MEAT
EVERY
SATURDAY
AT
TWELVE
```

Comment: If you've read all the lines, there are no more lines to read. Create a new `Scanner` from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. The problem ended up being that I need to create a new scanner class.

Answer (score 0):

The Condition is wrong Here

```
while (i <= strArray.length)
```

You can write

```
while (i < strArray.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the scanner cannot be reused. Since it reached the end of the file already.

Here is an alternative solution using standard Java 7 NIO:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public
class Reader
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("file.dat");
        Object[] myLines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myLines));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know the index of an array in java starts with `zero` so the last elements index will always be `lengthOfArray - 1`

When you do this

```
 while (i <= strArray.length)
```

Suppose your array contains 7 elements so the first element will be at zero index and it keep on adding the elements. Then a condition comes when i becomes 7 but still your while loop allows it because you have specified `i <= strArray.length` so it tries to add an element at seventh index but the last index of an array will always be `lengthOfArray - 1` in this example it will be 6 so it cannot find the seventh index and will throw an exception.

To solve this just remove the equal sign

```
    Scanner scannerForReading = new Scanner(new File("file.dat"));
    while (i < strArray.length && scannerForReading.hasNextLine()) {
        strArray[i] = scannerForReading.nextLine();
        System.out.println(strArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
```